# URL encoding when downloading a file in Flash

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I have a flash app that needs to download a file, whose name contains UTF-8 characters.

Internally, the filename is read from a UTF-8 XML file, e.g. "my filé.pdf".  The code goes something like this:

```
url = get_filename_from_XML();
req = new URLRequest( url );

ref = new FileReference();
ref.download( req );
```

The problem is that the URL is encoded in Latin1, i.e. the é is encoded as %E9 instead of %C3%A9 (according to FireBug).  How can I get Flash to encode the URL correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack:

```
url = decode( encodeURI( url ) );

req = new URLRequest( url );
```

The encodeURI turns it into Latin1, URL-encoded, then decode turns it into Latin1 text (effectively changing the internal encoding of the String).  The URLRequest then encodes the bytes correctly, using %C3%A9 for é.

Answer (score 0):

You could try escape() or encodeURI()
Check the docs:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

```
url = get_filename_from_XML();

url = escape(url);
//url = encodeURI( url );

req = new URLRequest( url );
```

Comment: The escape method gives me the same thing - %E9.  encodeURI correctly encodes it, but when I pass that to the URLRequest's constructor, it creates an error 2087 on the ref.download() method.